# TensorFlow: bincount with axis option

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, vectorization

In TensorFlow, I can get the count of each element in an array with tf.bincount:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
freq = tf.bincount(x)
tf.Session().run(freq, feed_dict = {x:[2,3,1,3,7]})
```

this returns

```
Out[45]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Is there a way to do this on a 2D tensor? i.e.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
freq = tf.axis_bincount(x, axis = 1)
tf.Session().run(freq, feed_dict = {x:[[2,3,1,3,7],[1,1,2,2,3]]})
```

that returns

```
[[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way I found to do this is to take advantage of broadcasting to compare all values in the tensor against the pattern `[0, 1, ..., length - 1]`, and then count the number of "hits" along the desired axis.

Namely:

```
def bincount(arr, length, axis=-1):
  """Count the number of ocurrences of each value along an axis."""
  mask = tf.equal(arr[..., tf.newaxis], tf.range(length))
  return tf.math.count_nonzero(mask, axis=axis - 1 if axis < 0 else axis)

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[2,3,1,3,7],[1,1,2,2,3]])
bincount(x, tf.reduce_max(x) + 1, axis=1)
```

returns:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=406, shape=(2, 8), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])>
```

Comment: Isn't this going to take a ton of memory if your length is large?

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this is given for numpy array:[Apply bincount to each row of a 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755244/apply-bincount-to-each-row-of-a-2d-numpy-array/34759071#34759071).
Make every row unique by adding `row_id * (max + 1)` to each row, and then find `bincount` for the flattened 1d-array and then reshaping it appropriately.

For `TF` make the following changes:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])

max_x_plus_1 = tf.reduce_max(x)+1
ids = x + max_x_plus_1*tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0])[:,None]
out = tf.reshape(tf.bincount(tf.layers.flatten(ids), 
                 minlength=max_x_plus_1*tf.shape(x)[0]), [-1, N])

tf.Session().run(out, feed_dict = {x:[[2,3,1,3,7],[1,1,2,2,3]]})
#[[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#[0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this myself and wrote a little function for it since there isn't a official implementation.

```
def bincount(tensor, minlength=None, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        return tf.bincount(tensor, minlength=minlength)
    else:
        if not hasattr(axis, "__len__"):
            axis = [axis]

        other_axis = [x for x in range(0, len(tensor.shape)) if x not in axis]
        swap = tf.transpose(tensor, [*other_axis, *axis])
        flat = tf.reshape(swap, [-1, *np.take(tensor.shape.as_list(), axis)])
        count = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.bincount(x, minlength=minlength), flat)
        res = tf.reshape(count, [*np.take([-1 if a is None else a for a in tensor.shape.as_list()], other_axis), minlength])
        return res
```

In there is a lot of handling for different edge cases.

The gist of this solution is the following part:

```
swap = tf.transpose(tensor, [*other_axis, *axis])
flat = tf.reshape(swap, [-1, *np.take(tensor.shape.as_list(), axis)])
count = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.bincount(x, minlength=minlength), flat)
```

- The `transpose` operation moves all axis that you want to `bincount` to the end of the tensor. For example if you would have a matrix that looks like `[100, 50, 20]` with axis `[0, 1, 2]` and you would like the `bincount` for axis `1`, this operation would swap axis 1 to the end and you would get a `[100, 20, 50]` matrix.
- The `reshape` operation flattens all other axis for which you don't want a `bincount` to a single dimension / axis.
- The `map_fn` operation maps a `bincount` onto every entry of the flattened dimension / axis.

You have to specify the `minlength` parameter. This is needed so all `bincount` results have the same length (or else the matrix wouldn't have a valid shape). This is probably the max value for your `tensor`. For me it was better to pass it as parameter since I already had this value and didn't need to retrieve it but you could also calculate it with `tf.reduce_max(tensor)`.

The full solution additionally reshapes it back to restore the other axes.
It also supports multiple axes and a single `None` axis in the tensor (for batching).

Answer (score 0):

[`tf.bincount()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bincount) accepts an array as argument but it aggregates the count across the array and doesn't work along some axis, at the moment. For example:

```
In [27]: arr
Out[27]: 
array([[2, 3, 1, 3, 7],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)

In [28]: x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
    ...: freq = tf.bincount(x)
    ...: tf.Session().run(freq, feed_dict = {x:arr})

# aggregates the count across the whole array
Out[28]: array([0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
# 0 occurs 0 times
# 1 occurs 3 times
# 2 occurs 3 times
# 3 occurs 3 times and so on..
```

So, at least as of now, there no way to pass the axis information to [`tf.bincount()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bincount).

---

However, a slightly inefficient way would be to pass one row at a time to [`tf.bincount()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/bincount) and get the results. And then finally combine these resultant 1D arrays as an array of desired dimensionality.

I'm unsure whether this is the most efficient way but anyway here is one way to loop over the tensor (along axis 0)

```
In [3]: arr = np.array([[2, 3, 1, 3, 7], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]], dtype=np.int32)
In [4]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [5]: for idx, row in enumerate(tf.unstack(arr)):
   ...:     freq = tf.bincount(row)
   ...:     print(freq.eval())
   ...:     
[0 1 1 2 0 0 0 1]
[0 2 2 1]
```

Comment: Ok I wouldn't mind do it in the for-loop way. In tf, what would be the best practice to do this?